# Lua, size of table (#table_name or table.getn(table_name), it returns sometimes 0

Tags: lua

When `#table_name` does return not 0 value?
And again, when `table.getn(table_name)` does return not 0 value?

Comment: What version of lua are you using?

Comment: If you just want to know whether a table `t` is empty, use `next(t)==nil` instead of `#t==0`.

Answer (score 7):

Go through the manual:

> **2.5.5 - The Length Operator**
>
> The length operator is denoted by the unary operator #. The length of a string is its number of bytes (that
> is, the usual meaning of string length when each character is one
> byte).
>
> The length of a table t is defined to be any integer index n
> such that t[n] is not nil and t[n+1] is nil; moreover, if t[1] is nil,
> n can be zero. For a regular array, with non-nil values from 1 to a
> given n, its length is exactly that n, the index of its last value. If
> the array has "holes" (that is, nil values between other non-nil
> values), then #t can be any of the indices that directly precedes a
> nil value (that is, it may consider any such nil value as the end of
> the array).

Answer (score 3):

If the keys in your table are not integers (strings for example) the length operator will return 0.